# How to list all "shared folders" and add "Authenticated Users" into "Share Permissions" without remove other Group or user name?

Tags: rights

I need some help to add the group "Authenticated Users" on all "Shares" with right "Change".

I can proceed manually but we have thousand of shares so I would like to proceed by script.

I'm able to list my share with (net view \Alias /all) but I don't know how to add the group "Authenticated Users" into "Share Permissions" with the right "Change".

The second point is: I have to keep groups already présents.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: forgot the "Hi" !

Comment: Update tags and question, please. What product your question is related for?